Which teams did Ronald Koeman play as a midfielder in?
Many time it's said that Ronald Koeman is the defender with most goals in football history. But he also played as a midfielder in his career.
I was wondering if his games as a midfielder were limited to some teams, or his dual playing positions were used everywhere. To give an example of another player, Javier Mascherano played always as a midfielder in Liverpool, West Ham, Corinthians, River and the argentine national team, he played as a defender and midfielder in Barcelona, and not sure in Hebai China and Estudiantes.
I was wondering this because many of his goals might come from him playing as a midfielder, meaning he wouldnt be the defender with most goals, but this is never mentioned
